# Tomcat and LDAP - can't get authentication working

Tags: tomcat, ldap

basically I've set up Tomcat to validate users via LDAP, but can't get my head around these OU paramteres... Here's link to paste with all needed configs and LDAP structure:

```
http://tny.cz/ce47c71f
```

also note comment there, AD tree is pretty expanded, I want to be able to log in as any user from any group in DC=comapny,DC=corp

can somebody help me to achieve it? I've really tried various configs and such, though got little idea about LDAP authentication.

Tomcat version is 5.5.36.

EDIT: this got me it working!

```
    <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
     debug="99"
     connectionName="..."
     connectionPassword="..."
     connectionURL="ldap://comp.corp:3268"
     userBase="dc=comp,dc=corp"
     userSearch="(sAMAccountName={0})"
     userSubtree="true"
     roleBase="dc=comp,dc=corp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.JNDIRealm"
debug="99"
connectionName="CN=admin,OU=Special,OU=Groups,DC=company,DC=corp"
connectionPassword="password"
connectionURL="ldap://company.corp:3268"
userBase="dc=company,dc=corp"
userSearch="(mail={0})"
roleBase="dc=company,dc=corp"/>
```

-jim